# Can't spot "Unreachable code"

Tags: java

There is something in my program that doesn't make sense. It may be my while statement that has embedded in it's loop several different if statements. But the main error is pointing after my while loop and I can't seem to figure it out. I commented where the error is.

Here is what the program looks like:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class MorseCode 
{
 public static void main (String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException
 {
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(new File("myfile.txt")); 
  String text = " "; 

while (keyboard.hasNextLine())
{
 text = keyboard.nextLine(); 
 morse(text); // Goes through morse(text);
 String code = ""; // String is declared 
 code = morse(text); 
 System.out.println(code); // prints the code which is being called upon morse(text)
 }
  keyboard.close(); 
}
 static String morse(String text)
 {
  String code = "";
  int i = 0;
  while (true) { 
  if (text.charAt(i) == 'a' || text.charAt(i) == 'A')
    System.out.print(".-");
  if (text.charAt(i) == 'b' || text.charAt(i) == 'B')
    System.out.print("-...");
  if (text.charAt(i) == 'c' || text.charAt(i) == 'C')
    System.out.print("-.-.");
  if (text.charAt(i) == 'd' || text.charAt(i) == 'D')
    System.out.print("-..");
  if (text.charAt(i) == 'e' || text.charAt(i) == 'e')
    System.out.print(".");
  if (text.charAt(i) == 'f' || text.charAt(i) == 'F')
    System.out.print("..-."); 
  if (text.charAt(i) == 'g' || text.charAt(i) == 'G')
    System.out.print("--.");
  if (text.charAt(i) == 'h' || text.charAt(i) == 'H')
    System.out.print("....");
  if (text.charAt(i) == 'i' || text.charAt(i) == 'I')
    System.out.print("..");
  if (text.charAt(i) == 'j' || text.charAt(i) == 'J')
    System.out.print(".---");
  if (text.charAt(i) == 'k' || text.charAt(i) == 'K')
    System.out.print("-.-");
  if (text.charAt(i) == 'l' || text.charAt(i) == 'L')
    System.out.print(".-..");
  if (text.charAt(i) == 'm' || text.charAt(i) == 'M')
    System.out.print("--");
  if (text.charAt(i) == 'n' || text.charAt(i) == 'N')
    System.out.print("-.");
  if (text.charAt(i) == 'o' || text.charAt(i) == 'O')
    System.out.print("---");
  if (text.charAt(i) == 'p' || text.charAt(i) == 'P')
    System.out.print(".--.");
  if (text.charAt(i) == 'q' || text.charAt(i) == 'Q')
    System.out.print("--.-");
  if (text.charAt(i) == 'r' || text.charAt(i) == 'R')
    System.out.print(".-.");
  if (text.charAt(i) == 's' || text.charAt(i) == 'S')
    System.out.print("...");
  if (text.charAt(i) == 't' || text.charAt(i) == 'T')
    System.out.print("-");
  if (text.charAt(i) == 'u' || text.charAt(i) == 'U')
    System.out.print("..-");
  if (text.charAt(i) == 'v' || text.charAt(i) == 'V')
    System.out.print("...-");
    if (text.charAt(i) == 'w' || text.charAt(i) == 'W')
    System.out.print(".--");
  if (text.charAt(i) == 'x' || text.charAt(i) == 'X')
    System.out.print("-..-");
  if (text.charAt(i) == 'y' || text.charAt(i) == 'Y')
    System.out.print("-.--");
  if (text.charAt(i) == 'z' || text.charAt(i) == 'Z')
    System.out.print("--..");
  if (text.charAt(i) == '1')
    System.out.print(".----");
  if (text.charAt(i) == '2')
    System.out.print("..---");
  if (text.charAt(i) == '3')
    System.out.print("...--");
  if (text.charAt(i) == '4')
    System.out.print("....-");
  if (text.charAt(i) == '5')
    System.out.print(".....");
  if (text.charAt(i) == '6')
    System.out.print("-....");
  if (text.charAt(i) == '7')
    System.out.print("--...");
  if (text.charAt(i) == '8')
    System.out.print("---..");
  if (text.charAt(i) == '9')
    System.out.print("----.");
  if (text.charAt(i) == '0')
    System.out.print("-----");
  if (text.charAt(i) == '-')
    System.out.print("...");
  if (text.charAt(i) == ' ')
    System.out.print(".......");
  i++;  
  }
   if (i < text.length());  //Unreachable code 
    return code;

 }
}
```

Comment: How do you terminate your loop?

Comment: You have an infinite loop there, how are you supposed to get to the statements below?

Answer (score 10):

Move the bracket down one (after the i++) so its like this:

```
        if (text.charAt(i) == '0')
            System.out.print("-----");
        if (text.charAt(i) == '-')
            System.out.print("...");
        if (text.charAt(i) == ' ')
            System.out.print(".......");
        i++;  
        if (i < text.length())  //Reachable code now :)
            return code;
        }
    }
}
```

That way you actually get to the spot where you check if your ready to break out

You could also change the condition of your while loop from true to (i < text.length()), but your current code suggests you were trying to do the above, but just misplaced a bracket :)

Also, not sure what your trying to do here; do you want to print it, or return it? The value of code is never changed from "", but you still return that. I think you should replace the prints with code+=, so that you'll actually return something appropriate, and then you could do System.out.println(morse("Something"));

Comment: Or better yet.. Look up the values in a map or enum.  There is no better code than the code someone else maintains.

Answer (score 7):

Your while loop never terminates.

If you want to iterate over the characters in your text string, I suggest you change:

`while (true) {`

to

`while (i < text.length()) {`

Then simply return the `code` after the while loop completes.

I would also suggest you use **if-else** statements rather than a series of if statements so that all the if conditions don't have to be evaluated for every character.

Answer (score 4):

It's your `while(true)`. The loop never ends, therefore the code after the loop is never reached.

Use a boolean variable that is set to true.

```
boolean x = true;
while (x) {...}
```

Comment: In ref to theglauber's post. I think the ; at the end of the `if` statement is a typo and should be a {.   `if (i < text.length()){`

Answer (score 3):

You using `while (true) {` - this will never terminate.

If you wish to use:

```
while (keyboard.hasNext()) {
```

then you will need to pass the Scanner instance to your morse method. Generally though it is best to have this method do one job only - translating. Why not use a `Map<String, String>` to store your morse translations and use have a translateMorse method?

Comment: ok, that's what I thought was wrong. Could I say something like

Answer (score 2):

Your program will be permanently stuck in the while(true) loop since, by definition, the true condition is always true.

Answer (score 2):

Your while loop should be
    `while (i < text.length()) {`

and the if statement that is unreachable should be removed and there you should just do
    `return code;`

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Your code will **never terminate** as its in an `Infinite while loop`.

**2.** You `while( i<text.length() )` **instead of** `while(true)`

**3.** I would further **discourage** the use of `if` or `if-else` ladder, its ok when there are two to three conditions to check, but **for something like in your above example**, use `switch statement`.